# Retaining Dimensions with FlexSlider

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, flexslider

I am using the new flex slider and I want to retain the dimensions of my images. It keeps re-sizing the images no matter what options that I use. Has anyone hard-coded, and option where you can retain a certain height and width for your FlexSlider viewport?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [Flexslider 2](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/,)

Try using a containing element with a class like, `.flexcontainer`, and with a set `width` or `max-width` in your css to match the width of your images:

```
<div class="flexcontainer">
    <div id="my-slider" class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">
        ...
        </ul>
    </div> 
</div>
```